# How to stretch button all over the grid, xaml

Tags: xaml, stackpanel, wpf-grid

I have a problem with stretching the button all over the grid.

My code look like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Button Content="Search" Background="#FF13D38D" Click="searchButton_Click" FontSize="48"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

But it didn't work for me, and stretch the button all over the grid, I tried maxwidth/maxheight but it also didn't work correctly anyone has an idea?

Comment: Remove the stackpanel and your problem is solved - stackpanels only take up the minimum amount of room to contain the child controls (no matter what you set their alignment to). Controls in a stackpanel will not stretch to fill the parent container. Grid cells, however, will stretch.

Comment: also remove Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" the Width and Height set to Auto won't matter because they would be re set from the Grid elements 

and the H/V Alignment = "Stretch" are the default value.

<Button Content="Search" Background="#FF13D38D" Click="searchButton_Click" FontSize="48" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" />

Comment: If the problem got solved , please add it as an answer yourself and accept it, rather than adding it to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
Remove the `StackPanel` (see [Charleh's comment below question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031683/how-to-stretch-button-all-over-the-grid-xaml#comment29831224_20031683)).

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Search" Background="#FF13D38D" Click="searchButton_Click" FontSize="48" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```